# AWS RDS aurora Mysql 5.6 cannot create table with engine different than default

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, myisam, amazon-aurora

## Problem: Can't create table with MyISAM storage engine on AURORA MySQL 5.6 RDS

### Configuration:

I have `RDS` with `Aurora MySQL 5.6.10a`.

`default_storage_engine` is set to `InnoDB` and cannot be modified (`Modifiable = false`).

When I run command

```
SHOW ENGINES
```

I receive:

```
+----------+---------+-------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine   | Support | Comment                 | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| 'MyISAM' | 'YES'   | 'MyISAM storage engine' | 'NO'         | 'NO' | 'NO'       |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

### My goal:

Creating table with `MyISAM` search engine on it.

### What happens:

When I try to create table with command:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `myTableId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latLong` point NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`myTableId`),
  SPATIAL KEY `point_storePoint_spatial_idx` (`latLong`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I receive:

```
0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1266 Using storage engine InnoDB for table 'myTable' Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1
```

What should I change to allow creating desired table?
Thank you in advance for response.

Comment: There is essentially no need for MyISAM any more.  Go with InnoDB.

Comment: Thank you Rick, according to MySQL 5.6 documentation:

SPATIAL INDEX creates an R-tree index. For storage engines that support nonspatial indexing of spatial columns, the engine creates a B-tree index. A B-tree index on spatial values is useful for exact-value lookups, but not for range scans.

Comment: And further:

Only MyISAM supports R-tree indexes on spatial types.
MyISAM supports both SPATIAL and non-SPATIAL indexes. Other storage engines support non-SPATIAL indexes

Comment: If the goal is to "find the nearest 10 Starbucks", take a peek at [_my implementation_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aurora does not support MyISAM.  If you absolutely have to have MyISAM, you can try MySQL RDS, but should be aware that that may affect the available features around data recovery, point-in-time restore, etc.

You can create spatial indexes in Aurora using the default (InnoDB) engine.

Edit:  There is a good article discussion the Aurora geospatial indexing at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-aurora-under-the-hood-indexing-geospatial-data-using-z-order-curves/ which claims that their implementation has 10x better performance than MySQL.

Comment: Some questions: Do I have to use POINT or GEOMETRY? And after that, do I have to setup the index properly and perhaps an option in Default Properties? This is suggested here but no instructions. Thanks a lot.
https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/amazon-aurora-update-spatial-indexing-and-zero-downtime-patching/

Comment: @Ricardo - that should probably be a separate question rather than a discussion in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Q: What does "MySQL compatible" mean?**

It means that most of the code, applications, drivers and tools you already use today with your MySQL databases can be used with Aurora with little or no change. The Amazon Aurora database engine is designed to be wire-compatible with MySQL 5.6 using the InnoDB storage engine. Certain MySQL features like the MyISAM storage engine are not available with Amazon Aurora.

For more info read the Aurora FAQ:
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/

Comment: Thank you, I was digging too deep and forgot to start from the beginning, which FAQ is.